# Error TS2563: The containing function or module body is too large for control flow analysis

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I upgraded my package.json in angular project. The migration was done from Angular 6 to 7. When I try to build, I saw this error in the console.

Error TS2563: The containing function or module body is too large for control flow analysis.

Here is my new package.json

```
{
  "name": "e-case-prototype",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --source-map=false",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-aot-disabled": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot false --build-optimizer false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.15",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "11.1.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.8",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^4.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.8.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.2.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "luxon": "^1.15.0",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^4.0.3",
    "ng2-charts": "2.2.3",
    "ng2-dnd": "5.0.2",
    "ngx-captcha": "^6.4.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "7.5.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "2.2.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^5.1.0",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "prismjs": "1.16.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "systemjs": "^3.1.6",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.15",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "12.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Here is the old package.json that was working

```
{
  "name": "e-case-prototype",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --source-map=false",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-aot-disabled": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot false --build-optimizer false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.3",
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "8.0.1",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",
    "angular-calendar": "0.25.2",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.6.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.6",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "2.22.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^3.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "5.0.2",
    "ngx-captcha": "^5.0.3",
    "ngx-color-picker": "6.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "1.0.10",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^2.13.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^3.1.0",
    "npm-check": "^5.7.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "prismjs": "1.14.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.21.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "10.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "6.0.3",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.13.0"
  }
}
```

I had already tried upgrading to different typescript version. I was limited by Angular as the version has to be between 3.1.1 and 3.3

The code was compiling on the previous typescript version of ^2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

How large is this function?  According to [this reference file in the TypeScript source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9c71eaf59040ae75343da8cdff01344020f5bba2/tests/baselines/reference/largeControlFlowGraph.errors.txt) this error is expected after a function has over 10,000 nodes in it.

```
==== tests/cases/compiler/largeControlFlowGraph.ts (1 errors) ====
    // The control flow graph for the following statement block is 10000 nodes deep. Check that
    // we gracefully handle this, possibly by issuing an error.
    const data = [];
    ~~~~~
!!! error TS2563: The containing function or module body is too large for control flow analysis.
data[0] = 0;
data[0] = 0;
data[0] = 0;

//they do this 10000 more times...

data[0] = 0;
data[0] = 0;
```

Comment: The function is 3879 lines long.

Comment: That is a big function... can't you break it into smaller functions?

Comment: @AaronBeall The file is dynamically generated. The method controls the properties of the HTML element so if there are a lot of HTML elements, it's going to be big.

Comment: @Chris Barr What do you mean by nodes. Does it mean the number of lines?

Comment: Nodes is like small unit of code.  A single line , it has nothing to o with line number.  A **200 line** function is a hugely massive function, but it sounds like you've written an entire application inside of a function. I don't think it's reasonable to expect a 3800 line function to work with no issues.  Break that up into smaller bits of code, what you have now is not only difficult to work with but it literally breaks the compiler.

Comment: Also, if you want to see example of what a "node" is in typescript, check out the name of the items in the enums from this file in the TypeScript source code.  things like `false` keyword, and equality check symbols `===`, and `if` statements, variable declarations and even `var` keywords. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6a559e37ee0d660fcc94f086a34370e79e94b17a/src/compiler/types.ts

Answer (score 0):

File name: `tsconfig.base.json`
Simple change `"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true` to `"fullTemplateTypeCheck": false`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in my Angular Project.

**The Solution is:**

I was using

`{"strictTemplates": true}` in  `angularCompilerOptions` in **tsconfig.json**

When I changed it to `"strictTemplates": false`

The compilation was Successful!